# My drop down menus are displaying the same selected value despite being assigned different values.

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have the following code:

```
    if(!Page.IsPostBack){
        dropDownMenu1.SelectedValue = "1";
        lblError.Text += dropDownMenu1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        dropDownMenu2.SelectedValue = "2";
        lblError.Text += dropDownMenu2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        dropDownMenu3.SelectedValue = "3";
        lblError.Text += dropDownMenu3.SelectedValue.ToString();
        lblError.Text += dropDownMenu1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        lblError.Text += dropDownMenu2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        lblError.Text += dropDownMenu3.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

However, when I execute the code, all three drop down menus have the value of 3. The output of lblError.Text is 123333.

There is no other code that changes the value of the drop down menus, and the value in the drop down menus are only dynamically set by this code, and are never set statically (i.e. in the properties).

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try moving this to the `Page_Initialize` handler instead?

Comment: Are DropDownMenu1,2,3 the id's of the controls or are those locally declared variables? Local variables that are not assigned correctly would explain this issue if all three variables were mistakenly pointing to the same control.